# Can this implement Matlabpool in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

Im using the Matpower - Matlab toolbox in parallel computing and building the computer cluster to simulate the programme which is shown below:

```
matlabpool open job1 5  % matlabpool means computer cluster

spmd %the statement from the Parallel computing toolbox
    % Run all the statements in parallel 
    % first part of code
    if labindex==1
        runopf('casea');
    end
    % second part of code
    if labindex==2
        runopf('caseb');
    end
end

matlabpool close;
```

When the labindex is 1 the first part of code in this program is running in "computer1" in the cluster, and so forth when the labindex is 2, then the second part of code in the program is "running in computer2". My question is the main code shown above running in sequence or in parallel?

By which I mean, does the second part code has to wait to be executed until the first part of code is executed or two parts of codes can be executed parallel at the two different computers in the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code between `spmd` and corresponding `end` is sent to all workers (5 in your case) and they execute these instructions *in parallel*. Then, in your code you instructed worker #1 to execute `runopf('casea');` and worker #2 `runopf('caseb');`. Workers #3 to #5 will effectively do nothing.

Technically, worker #2 will execute `runopf('caseb');` a little later. The delay appears because worker #2 will also check the first `if` statement (but will not execute the code in it).

Comment: Is this delay of worker #2 until worker #1 executed or just due to the if statement?

Comment: Yes, just because of `if` statement. "Parallel computing" means that worker executes its own code at the same time when other workers execute their own code.